# What's the meaning of "pole the strength" in this example?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I heard it in a [documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teExcLU00OY) at the second minute the speaker says:

> We explore who poles/pull (I could be wrong about this word because it has no subtitle) the
> strength.

What does the "pole or pull the strength" means here, I did a little digging but didn't find what makes sense here, since I'm not sure it "pull" or "pole"

Comment: I believe the accepted answer is right but I think you meant 'poll' in your question.  'Poll' means to query or ask for information.  'Pole' as a verb would mean to jab or poke with a long stick.

Comment: @user48 Could you find a reference link that did not demand personal details?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin the only channel that had uploaded this documentary is the one I shared, that's the YouTube's feature not me, as you know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have misheard the phrase. It is actually this:

> We explore who pulls the strings . . .

To **pull the strings** is an idiom. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull%20the%20strings) suggests this definition and provides an example

> to control someone or something often in a secret way
> *It turned out that his brother was the person **pulling the strings** behind the operation.*

[Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/usage/pull-strings/) suggests this origin:

> The phrase **pull strings** may be traced to the 1860s, and refers to puppetry in use at the time that employed the use of  pulling strings in order to make the puppets perform.